# Zend - refactoring to include a form globally on site

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I currently have a search form in the search controller, so the only way I can get to it is through `/search/`. I have to refactor my code so that this search form appears not only in the Search Controller but also globally throughout the site.

( The code isnt *exact* as I had to retype some of it )

My class that extends `Zend_Form` is located in `application/forms/forms/SearchForm.php`:

```
class Form_SearchForm extends Zend_Form {

    public function init() {};

}
```

My search controller is something like..

```
class SearchController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function search() {
        $searchForm = new Form_SearchForm();
        $this->view->form = $searchForm;
    }
}
```

In my Bootstrap.php I have an autoloader for models:

```
protected function _initAutoload() {
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array(
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
        'namespace' => '',
        'resourceTypes' => array(
            'form' => array(
            'path' => 'forms',
            'namespace' => 'Form_',
            ),
            'model' => array(
            'path' => 'models/',
            'namespace' => 'Model_',
            ),
        ),
        )
    );

return $autoLoader;
```

}

I'm wondering where I can store my code so that globally the search form is generated in the view.

My global layout file is located in `application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml` and currently spits out a dynamic content area:

```
<div id="main">
    <?php echo $this->layout()->content;?>
</div>
```

Should I just add the form to this layout.phtml or is there some generic controller I should use?

Edit: Sorry for not specifying this too, but what if for example I wanted to not include it for 1-2 special pages ( maybe an admin section ).. if I hardcoded it into layout.phtml it would still appear.. or should I serve a different layout file to say, an admin area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a `searchAction()` is not good for performance because it requires a brand new dispatch cycle. If, and only if, you have very complex logic that justifies a separate action, you could [create a Controller Plugin and add `searchAction()` to the ActionStack](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.view.html#performance.view.action.actionstack). If you are only instantiating/assigning the form or if you don't need the search form for *every* request, it's not an optimal solution.

---

Another possibility would be to instantiate and assign the form in the bootstrap. This kind-of breaks separation of concerns, but provides better performance.

```
protected function _initSearchForm()
{
    $this->bootstrap('view');

    $view = $this->getResource('view');
    $searchForm = new Form_SearchForm();

    $view->searchForm = $searchForm;
    return $searchForm;
}
```

---

Finally, my **preferred** solution would be a custom view helper:

```
<?php

class My_View_Helper_SearchForm extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function searchForm()
    {
        $searchForm = new Form_SearchForm();
        return $searchForm;
    } 
}
```

For either of these solutions, you'd ideally output the form in your layout file to minimise duplication.

layout.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->searchForm() ?>
```

And create an alternate layout `admin.phtml` for admin area pages. This gives you the flexibility to change the admin pages significantly when new requirements pop up.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can create your Form in a Controller Plugin and add it to view vars somehow (by Zend_Controller_Front?), which are accessible in layout, too. But it's too complicated in current ZF version (or I'm too dumb)
2. You can make Form_SearchForm a singleton

   ```
   class Form_SearchForm ... {
        static function getInstance() {
             static $instance;
             if (!$instance)
                 $instance = new Form_SearchForm();
             return $instance;
        }
   }
   ```

   Now instead of creating new Form_SearchForm() just get it as

   ```
   $form = Form_SearchForm::getInstance();
   ```
3. You can put an instance of Form_SearchForm to the registry
4. I probably have missed a very cool a simple way :)

Comment: I'm sorry you lost me, do you mind expanding on that and dumbing it down for my newbie-self?

Comment: which option do you prefer? I don't think I know the right way. But the most right, I think, is the first, but It's too complicated now.

Comment: make a class a singleton is simple, I'll add a code for that now. How to add an instance of Form_SearchForm to the Zend_Registry you can figure out by yourself :)

Comment: Just curious, what do you achieve by making it a singleton?

Comment: Richard Nguyen exactly what's needed: I'm making sure it will be created only once, so if the form was processed it will store values and validation results

Answer (score 1):

I would split it into a partial and a place holder.

in layout.phtml:

```
<?php if($searchForm = $this->placeHolder('searchForm'): ?>
  <?php echo $searchForm; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

then in your views you can call:

```
<?php $this->placeHolder('searchForm')->set($this->partial('search-from.phtml', 'search')); ?>
```

IF you wanted you could even make a search view helper that basically does the place holder call.

The Controller plugin would be better if you have more pages that dont need it than d though. I would still probably use placeholder though to accomplish it. That way you can easily override or append to it later on a view-by-view basis without calling anything on the front controller.

Comment: How would he use the form from controller?

Comment: you have access to the view and thus the view helpers controller.

if you are talking about actually constructing the from with a Zend_Form then instead of calling the partial helper you could call the action helper going to the Search_Controller. assuming $view is a Zend_View instance... and 'form' is the name of the action which outputs the form...

$view->placeHolder('searchForm')->set($view->action('form', 'search', 'default));

Comment: sorry I'm confused, would I have to have the second code snippet in every single view?

Comment: Yes, any view you want the form to appear on. IF you have more views that have it than dont have it then an front controller plugin is easier... less maintenance.